# Concurrent Connection Apache and Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5, ubuntu-18.04

I'm a bit confused by a problem that has only become more apparently lately and I'm hoping that someone might be able to point me in the direction of either where I might look for appropriate settings, or if I am running into another problem they have come across before.

I have a Laravel application and a private server that I use for our little museum. Now as the application has become more complex, the lag is noticeable and you can see how it almost lines up the connections, finishing one request before moving along to the next, whether it be api, ajax, view responses, whatever.

I am running Apache 2.4.29 and my Ubuntu Server is 18.04.1.

I have been looking around but not much has helped, in regards to connections settings, if I look at my phpinfo() I see this `Max Requests  Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100` but I believe these are just fine the way they are.

If I check my memory I think it says I have 65 GB of available memory, with 5 being used in caching. When reviewing the live data, the memory never crosses into the GB territory and solely remains in the MB territory. This server is absolutely only used for this Laravel project, so I don't have to worry about messing with other projects, I'd just like to make sure this application is getting the best use it can for its purpose.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, I know there's a chance the terms I am searching for are incorrect, or maybe just outdated, so if there are any potential useful resources out there, I'd appreciate those as well.

Thank you so much!

Comment: with this amount of memory i think you need to look at your code again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to be able to tell since there a lot of details lacking but here some things that can give you a direction of where to look:

1. Try downloading htop via apt-get and see what happens on your CPU/RAM load with each request to the server.
2. Do you use php-fpm to manage the php requests? This might help in finding out if the problem lies in your PHP code or in apache configuration
3. Did you try deploying to a different server? Do you still see the lagging on the other server as well? If not, this indicates a misconfiguration problem and not an issue with your code.
4. Do you have other processes that are running in the background and might slow things down? Cron? Laravel Queue?
5. If you try to install another app on the server (let's say phpmyadmin) is it slow as well or it works fine?

Try to take it from here. Best of luck.

Comment: A little update, and I will update based on your numbers. 1) Have added and as I thought if I have multiple folks from different places (just to be safe) try to access and the CPU/RAM use rarely (and if it does then barely) hits 1% of total usage. 2) I don't but that will be my next task. 3) I have a new server coming in later next week for another project, but do you have any resources to look around for to possibly locate a misconfiguration if there was one? 4) I have one cron at the moment, which runs every minute but rarely does anything.

Comment: Continued... - on 4) ... just to make sure things don't pile up (such as temporary files or status changes). 5) Adding phpmyadmin makes me wonder if there is something I'm not noticing with the Laravel itself as I can load/reload the PhpMyAdmin page (along with others as trying to force it to deal with the multiple connections) multiple times while it takes the Laravel several seconds of booting.

Comment: OK, so if phpmyadmin works fine it means that there might not be a problem with the configuration and neither with the server per se. Maybe as you suggest your are missing something in the laravel code?

Comment: You might be right, so I have rigged up a new temp server and have just created a fresh laravel installation, using the same backend database. Using the Laravel Debugbar I have seen the booting drop from 1.2 to 8.5 seconds in the old application to 3.1 milliseconds in the new one (and still using the same database). I set up a page where it basically loads the exact same information in the same html template and the load times are that different. So it has to be something in the old Laravel project that is causing major problems... unfortunately I'm at a loss on that one

Comment: Thank you for your help though, I'll accept your answer solely for the purpose of it having successfully narrowed down to it being a Laravel issue in itself and not one of the server or any other handling issues.